# How to create a random matrix (without using numpy)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create an array. When the number of rows and columns are not same, an empty [] appears at the end.

I also want it to be displayed in correct matrix form of [m x n]

I am new to using  Python language and this is my first question.

I hope to find a solution to the problem.

```py
import random

m = int(input("Rows : "))
n = int(input("Columns : "))
Mat = []
for i in range(0,n):
    Mat.append([])
for i in range(0,m):
    for j in range(0,n):
        Mat[i].append(j)
        Mat[i][j] = 0
        Mat[i][j] = random.randint(1,100)
print(Mat)
```

Example:

```
Columns : 2
Rows : 3
```

Output:

```
[[7, 49, 61], [47, 2, 40], []]
```

I need it like this:

```
[[7, 49, 61],
 [47, 2, 40]]
```

Comment: `mat = [[random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(m)]`

Comment: Thnx But what about the shape !

Comment: you are not going to get the same kind of output, for your `mat`, as a numpy array when you print it out. unless you are using `pprint.pprint(mat)` or similar to print out `mat`.

Comment: In your inner loop, you could just be doing this instead of those three lines `Mat[i].append(random.randint(1,100))` but the list comprehension above is much better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here, where you *specifically* add one row for every column the user requests:

```
for i in range(0,n):
    Mat.append([])
```

Instead, use the variable for rows:

```
for i in range(0, m):
    Mat.append([])
```

There are several places where you are doing extra work, such as setting a value and then immediately destroying it.

Comment: Thank you mr Prune

Comment: Note that this is a fix for only the immediate problem.  The various comments are very good refinements for your code.